# How to generate an ER diagram WITHOUT foreign keys (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-relationship, erd, workbench

I have to generate an ERD from my database to a school project. My teachers want the ER to not have foreign keys, only various relationships between the various entities. I have tried Visual Paradigm and now MySQL workbench using the reverse engineering option, but all of them generate the diagram with foreign keys, and I can't delete them.

Is there any option or other programs that generate the diagram according to these rules?

Comment: LucidChart of Draw.io are both really good free programs that you can use to make ERD diagrams which could work for what you need.

Comment: You can draw the ERD using DIA (for Windows)

Comment: Dear @Miguel Martins how ERD relations without foreign key, relation mean foreign key

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. Itried gliffy, wich is similar to draw.io, but they share a problem, i can't seem to find how to draw depent relationships there.
I forgot to mention that i have a mac and a virtual machine with ubuntu, but no windows unfortunately. 
@GoudaElalfy my teacher says that a diagram with foreign keys on the columns are not true ERs, they say that the relationships between entities are enough to represent foreign keys. I don't know if I am making myself clear.

Comment: @GoudaElalfy A relation is NOT the same as a foreign key.  A relation associates (usually different) values from one or more domains, a foreign key constraint defines one domain as a subset of another.

Comment: @MiguelMartins try drawing an ERD in Chen's original notation.  Tools like Visual Paradigm and MySQL Workbench are really just drawing table diagrams.

Comment: I mean there is no relations without foreign keys

Comment: Technically, the concept defined by the word "relation" in the relational model is actually implemented as a "table" in SQL.  Foreign key constraints enforce (and, indirectly, define) relation*ships*, not relations.    Relational databases are so-called, not (as commonly assumed) because of relationships, but because data is normalized into tables (relations).  And, someone should tell the teacher they are doing it wrong.

Comment: Relationships (in the Entity Relationship model) are relations.  Chen distinguished "entity relations" and "relationship relations".  A relation is any association of domains, an entity relation is a composition of binary relationships (attributes) with a particular domain as subject and a relationship relation is one in which the subject isn't a single domain.  However, the product of domains is still a domain and a tuple of values is still a value, and so a relationship relation can be viewed as an entity relation if the relationship has attributes.

Comment: Foreign key constraints are relations in the schema, not in the logical data model.  A database with absolutely no foreign key constraints can still be used in a meaningful way as long as the data is valid.  Foreign key constraints just maintain integrity.  They don't influence which values (from the constrained domains) we choose to relate and they don't influence how we're able to join tables.

Comment: It sounds like your teacher wants an ER model, rather than a relational model.  That's a good distinction to understand, and is insufficiently taught or appreciated these days.  In an ER model, relationships are identified but not implented.

Comment: Thanks for the support guys. I didn't find a program that used the "notation" I was looking to represent dependant relationships (without including FK on the entities), so I did my best to represent them on draw.io (i marked them with a tag and explained it on the notes section). Nowadays the difference between ER and relational model are a little foggy.

Answer (score 1):

Consider distinguishing between ERD (conceptual or logical level) and Data Structured Diagram or physical ERD.

A logical ERD is functional specification. It does not show / specify database columns but entities, their attributes and relationships. A possibly purely technical attribute like a foreign key is not required on this specification level. The relationship between the entities are already represented by lines.

Adding the foreign keys is only require to specify the additional DB columns on the physical level for the mapping of the model to a database schema.